# Hadith: I have been informed about everything that will happen until the Day of Judgment

Tags: hadith, source-identification

The above hadith was briefly mentioned in a Friday sermon without mentioning the source. Can someone confirm with the source?

Comment: The word "everything" makes this statement doubtful, all I know is that there's limited knowledge on that. I was not able to find anything that goes ahead with this statement so far. But Allah knows best!